# VBA, FindelementbyXpath, NoSuchElementError, When I copy&paste the xpath, then my code run well. However When play again my code, then error..why?

Tags: html, vba, selenium

i want to make "instagram Direct Message SENDING MECRO"

URL = [www.instagram.com/direct/inbox](http://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox)
`driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button/div/svg").Click`

WHEN I open the link, and copy&paste the xpath,
then my code run well
However, after run one time,
run my code again,

then 'NoSuchElementError'... why...? what shoud i do..?

(i also use selenium)

**full code :**

```
Sub Sending_DM()
Dim driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim username As String, Login_ID As String, Login_PW As String




Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
driver.Start
driver.Wait (2000)


username = Sheet3.Range("B2").Value    'B2 = User ID = username
Login_ID = Sheet3.Range("a1").Value
Login_PW = Sheet3.Range("a2").Value

driver.Get "https://www.instagram.com/" & username


'-----------Login
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""loginForm""]/div/div[1]/div/label/input").SendKeys (Login_ID) ' MY INSTAGRAM ID
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""loginForm""]/div/div[2]/div/label/input").SendKeys (Login_PW) ' My instagram PW
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""loginForm""]/div/div[3]").Click

driver.Wait (4000)

driver.Get "https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/"


'-----------Sending DM
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button/div/svg").Click
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").SendKeys (Sheet3.Range("c1"))
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button/div").Click
driver.Wait (1000)

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea").SendKeys (Sheet3.Range("c2").Value) 'Sheet3.range("c2") = recipient ID
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button").Click

Sheet3.Range("d2") = "o" 'Sending Check

End ()
```

Comment: They probably make the html dynamic to specifically prevent people from doing things like you are trying to do.

Comment: @braX then i can't solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have been trying and full error stack trace ? looks like we are running into locators issue

Comment: @cruisepandey i share the code!

Answer (score 0):

okay we are running into wrong locator issue.

replace this line

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button/div/svg").Click
```

with this :

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/button/div/*").Click
```